# How to export data to XLSB file in PHP using shared server

Tags: php, xlsb

I am using shared server i have a cpanel access but not finding any way to implement.

i'm getting this error but can't found any solution for shared server.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'COM' not found
```

Below code php file code:

```
// include("DataType.inc");

header("Content-Type: text/html");

echo "Tutorial 29<br>";
echo "----------<br>";

// Create an instance of the class that exports Excel files
$workbook = new COM("EasyXLS.ExcelDocument");

// Create two sheets
$workbook->easy_addWorksheet_2("First tab");
$workbook->easy_addWorksheet_2("Second tab");

// Get the table of data for the first worksheet
$xlsFirstTable = $workbook->easy_getSheetAt(0)->easy_getExcelTable();

// Add data in cells for report header
for ($column=0; $column<5; $column++)
{
    $xlsFirstTable->easy_getCell(0,$column)->setValue("Column " . ($column + 1));
    $xlsFirstTable->easy_getCell(0,$column)->setDataType($DATATYPE_STRING);
}

// Add data in cells for report values
for ($row=0; $row<100; $row++)
{
    for ($column=0; $column<5; $column++)
    {
        $xlsFirstTable->easy_getCell($row+1,$column)->setValue("Data ".($row + 1).", ".($column + 1));
        $xlsFirstTable->easy_getCell($row+1,$column)->setDataType($DATATYPE_STRING);
    }
}

// Set column widths
$xlsFirstTable->easy_getColumnAt(0)->setWidth(100);
$xlsFirstTable->easy_getColumnAt(1)->setWidth(100);
$xlsFirstTable->easy_getColumnAt(2)->setWidth(100);
$xlsFirstTable->easy_getColumnAt(3)->setWidth(100);

// Export the XLSB file
echo "Writing file: C:\Samples\Tutorial29.xlsb<br>";
$workbook->easy_WriteXLSBFile("./Tutorial29.xlsb");

// Confirm export of Excel file
if ($workbook->easy_getError() == "")
    echo "File successfully created.";
else
    echo "Error encountered: " . $workbook->easy_getError();

// Dispose memory
$workbook->Dispose();
```

Anyone have solution for this kind of issue advance thank you.

Comment: Why not use PHPSpreadsheet that does not need COM which is a Microsoft (needs windows) concept

Comment: Are you on a Windows or Unix server?

Comment: @RiggsFolly PHPSpreadsheet does't support XLSB excel formate. and i have Unix server

Comment: Then i dont think a COM Object is going to work on unix

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ok no problem thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The error is cause by the PHP server that does not support the COM dlls written in .NET. You must add an extension to your PHP server in php.ini file.

```
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

https://www.easyxls.com/manual/troubleshooting/class-com-not-found.html

UPDATE: This is the solution for the error that you get, but I have just noticed that you are on Unix. The COM objects are not supported on Unix. You must install [EasyXLS for Java](https://www.easyxls.com/trials#java) and also [PHP/Java Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/).